# SVG positioning relative to the end of text

Tags: svg

I'm dynamically generating SVG to display data in a webpage. If I have a `<text>` section without a defined width, it will display the text in one line. Is it possible to position a path at the end of that line? Since the text is dynamically generated, I don't know its width in advance.

Comment: It is maybe implicit in the question that the text needs to be aligned to the left, but can it be aligned to the right? Can you maybe create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That would help answering the question (before I ask more questions).

Comment: call get getComputedTextLength on the text and position the path after that point.

Comment: use [`text-anchor: end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) and set the `y` attribute to the "end of the line".